# How to reset Gotcha statement in Python

Tags: python, list, procedures

I am trying to use a Gotcha statement to hold a list of variables for comparison. But at the end of my procedure I want to reset this list so that it is blank and the process can be restarted. Here is a simple example of what I want, and what I am actually getting:

```
def append_to(element, reset, to = []):
    if reset == 'reset':
        to = []
        return
    to.append(element)
    return to

my_list = append_to(12, 'Not reset')
print my_list

my_other_list = append_to(42, 'Not reset')
print my_other_list

append_to(1, 'reset')

my_list = append_to(13, 'Not reset')
print my_list

my_other_list = append_to(43, 'Not reset')
print my_other_list
```

This is the output:

```
[12]
[12, 42]
[12, 42, 13]
[12, 42, 13, 43]
```

Output desired:

```
[12]
[12, 42]
[13]
[13,43]
```

How can I go about resetting this list? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll use `del to[:]` (or `to.clear()` on 3.3+). Writing `to = []` binds to a *local* variable.

Using `append` *modifies* the object which is pointed to by the local variable; this happens to also be pointed to by the caller, which is why the `append` is working.

This is exactly the misunderstanding that [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) was made for. [Here's a visualization of your code.](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+append_to(element,+reset,+to+%3D+%5B%5D)%3A%0A++++if+reset+%3D%3D+'reset'%3A%0A++++++++to+%3D+%5B%5D%0A++++++++return%0A++++to.append(element)%0A++++return+to%0A%0Amy_list+%3D+append_to(12,+'Not+reset')%0Aprint+my_list%0A%0Amy_other_list+%3D+append_to(42,+'Not+reset')%0Aprint+my_other_list%0A%0Aappend_to(1,+'reset')%0A%0Amy_list+%3D+append_to(13,+'Not+reset')%0Aprint+my_list%0A%0Amy_other_list+%3D+append_to(43,+'Not+reset')%0Aprint+my_other_list&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0)

Comment: Python 2.x's `list` does not have `clear` method unlike `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

`to = []` does not affect the original list. It just make the local variable to reference the new list.

Use slice notation or `del` statement to clear the list in-place.

```
def append_to(element, reset, to = []):
    if reset == 'reset':
        to[:] = []
        # or  del to[:]
        return
    to.append(element)
    return to
```